# How to call the function?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, event-handling

I need to get the position of the mouse on click in a form, and save the `x` and `y` coordinates. I made this simple function:

```
 public void kokot (MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
    this.Invalidate();
 }
```

How can I call it? When I try `kokot()` it doesn't work of course, because there are no arguments. So what arguments should I use in this case? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not a C# programmer, so giving just a small hint: you probably have to set kokot as an event handler. Event handlers are functions that you don't call directly but are "called back" (hence they're called "callback functions") by some library when an event is fired.

Comment: Winform or Webform? : | . @Felice Pollano: I think maybe he just  doesn't know how to "choose" a correct answer : )

Comment: That's not the proper signature for an event handler function. Why not let Visual Studio create these for you automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseClick);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = e.X;
        int y = e.Y;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question pls? I work on simple Paint Program ...so dont want to draw on Form but on "PANEL ???" so i made it Panel1.MouseClick+=new MouseEventHandler(Panel1_MouseClick). It works, but when i draw something its not seen. On Form it was. What is wrong?

Comment: I need 15 reputation to use it dont I?

Answer (score 0):

Add overload to the function that accept two integers:

```
public void kokot (int X, int Y)
{
   x = X;
   y = Y;
   this.Invalidate();
}
```

Then call it like this from anywhere in your code:

```
Point position = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
kokot(position.X, position.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subcsribe to the forms MouseClick Event.

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseClick);
```